# How can I overwrite the to string method of an R6Class in R language?

Tags: r, class, tostring, r6

I've tried by adding a to_string() function to the public part of the Class, but I'm looking for a method, like override in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString()` is an S3 geneic, so it can be defined for your class using `toString.{className}`

```r
MyClass <- R6::R6Class(
  "MyClass",
  list(i = 0)
)

toString.MyClass <- function(x, ...) {
  paste("i is", x$i)
}

my_object <- MyClass$new()
toString(my_object)
#> [1] "i is 0"
my_object$i <- 1
toString(my_object)
#> [1] "i is 1"
```

You can see it is a S3 generic by looking at the source

```r
toString
#> function (x, ...) 
#> UseMethod("toString")
#> <bytecode: 0x55fb2afe7d68>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

`UseMethod` means it will forward the call based on the class of the first argument (`x`) and if no implementation of `toString` for the specific class is given, `toString.default()` will be invoked instead.